# Pyramid: why NewRequest subscribers calls 3 times on every request?

Tags: python, pyramid

It was interesting to me and I've checked it. As you can read `NewRequest` subscribers are called 3 times on each request (or 7 times with debug_toolbar enabled...) while `BeforeRender` subscribers are called 1 time on each request (> 30 times with debug_toolbar enabled).

So, if I want to connect **mongodb** to my project through `NewRequest` event it will be done 3 times for each request...

Why is that? Why should server do the same job 3 times on each request?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You shouldn't create a connection to MongoDB within subscribers that is. I wrote an addon for pyramid. The connection is done on startup. The db handle is done in the app_factory or root_factory. In other word it's just a call to get a db handle from the connection that is created on startup. You can call it multiple time, it won't create new connections and it can be called anytime as long as you have a request. Creating a subscriber to setup a db isn't a good thing in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pyramid does not call `NewRequest` more than once per request. The only reason this would happen is if you are registering your subscriber multiple times accidentally. Another common reason people think it is called multiple times is that the browser usually follows requests with a favicon request, but that only accounts for 2 invocations. Can you show any output or describe your problem more to convince me that the subscriber really is being invoked more than once?

`BeforeRender` will be called multiple times (once for every template rendered). When the debug toolbar is enabled there is a lot of stuff being rendered on each request but even then 30 sounds more like 3 times what I would expect.

It's not a good idea to connect to your database in a `NewRequest` subscriber, in general, because that subscriber is invoked for static resources as well (literally all requests). A better pattern is to create a lazy/reified property on the `request` object via `config.set_request_property`. This will connect the first time you use the database in each request, and have no performance penalty when you do not.

Comment: Also note that any other static resource will fire a NewRequest (at least, when developing). That is: js, css, images, etc. It's normal for a page to load several other files after the initial request. When in production, it's recommended to serve those files with the web server directly, instead of serving them with the app.